# WPF ObjectConstant instance has been disposed (EF) when trying to access included table's attributes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have been having difficulties with Entity Framework's `using dbContext`. Here is an example of my code:

```
public List<tblProductIndication> ConseilsPrudence { get; set; }


using (var db = new labEntities())
     {
         ConseilsPrudence = db.tblProductIndication.Where(s => s.ProductID == ProductMatID && s.IndicationID == 139)
         .Include(s => s.tblIndicationText)
         .Include(s => s.tblIndicationText.IndicationTextValue)
         .Include(s => s.tblIndicationText.IndicationTextCode)
         .ToList();
     }
```

Here is a minified version of my xaml.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ConseilsPrudence, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CanUserAddRows="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding tblIndicationText.IndicationTextCode}" Width="0.2*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text" Binding="{Binding tblIndicationText.IndicationTextValue}" Width="0.2*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The problem is that even after adding all the Includes, I still get the following error when trying to access `tblIndicationText.IndicationTextCode` or `tblIndicationText.IndicationTextValue` in my `Datagrid`:

**"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."**

I know the cause of the error is that I am trying to access the result even though the `db Object (The labEntities Context)` has been disposed.

However, I don't understand why it's not possible to access the directly linked table `tblIndicationText` since it has been `Included` in the initial query.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Edit 1:** Following the suggestion of @mm8, I have tried the following

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

var test =  testMat = dbContext.tblMATProduct
.Where(s => s.ProductID == ProductMatID)
.Include(s => s.tblFormat)
.FirstOrDefault();

var result = testMat.tblFormat;
```

Here is the result:

[image]

tblFormat should however not be null. This is what evaluates to with the default lazyloading:

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

var test =  testMat = dbContext.tblMATProduct
.Where(s => s.ProductID == ProductMatID)
.Include(s => s.tblFormat)
.FirstOrDefault();

var result = testMat.tblFormat;
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't remember if it has an incidence, but did you try to put the `Includes` before the `Where` in your EF query ?

Comment: What's your EF version? Based on your current codes I can't get your error. Everything work as expected

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour Thanks for your comment, you put me on the right track. I think the problem is that I was using EF Core instead of Entity Framework! :)

Answer (score 2):

You should turn off lazy loading to load all child entities upfront before you dispose the context:

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

If you apply lazy loading of child entities, they are being loaded on demand when there is no context around any more.

Comment: I have edited the post (Edit 1) to show what happened when I tried implementing what you suggested.